# How to preprocess steps on Apache before sending a page to the User

Tags: apache, apache-modules

I have an Apache web server and I need to do some processes outside the web server when a user requests a certain page.
I will try to be more clear: when a user requests page X, I have to start an external program, passing it some session parameters, wait for response, and then send the requested page to the user.

Is this possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used apache ext_mod_filter: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

Performances are not that great, but for my purposes it is ok.